# Java- Passing a variable to the end of a number

Tags: java, variables, math

I'm trying to figure out how to pass in a variable into random parts of a math problem. This is a simple example of my problem

public class EquationY {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

     double x = 5;

double y = 4.6x + 34.2 ;

 System.out.println("y is " + y);
}
```

}

All I need to do is change the x to a 5 so it will read 4.65 + 34.2

---

For any of you that might not be fed up with me yet, let me know if this code is acceptable or should I start looking to find an easier way

12.3x^4 - 9.1x^3 + 19.3x^2 - 4.6x + 34.2

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
     double x = 5;

double y = Math.pow(12.3 + x/100, 4) - Math.pow(9.1 + x/100, 3) + Math.pow(19.3 + x/100, 2) - (4.6 + x/100) + 34.2 ;

 System.out.println("y is " + y);
}
```

y is 22901.02463125001

Comment: sorry what ? <!------>

Comment: Why on earth do you want to do that? I mean what's the usecase?

Comment: Technically, a number has no end. `4.6` = `4.60000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 .....`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you're trying to take a number and insert it to any location within any value in an equation, you probably should be treating all the values in the equation as strings. Then you can perform the insert easily and convert all the values to doubles afterwords.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    double x = 5;

    String z = 4.6 + String.valueOf((int)x);
    double y = Double.parseDouble(z) + 34.2 ;
    System.out.println("y is " + y);
}
```

This will give the answer you wanted.

Comment: this method can be used whenever you don't have an decimal point in value 'x' ie: x = 5.2

Answer (score 1):

you can do this way

```
double x=0.05;
double y = (4.6+x) + 34.2 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 double x = 0.05;
 double y = (4.6 + x) + 34.2 ;
```

instead of

```
 double x = 5;
 double y = 4.6x + 34.2 ;
```

Comment: is there any way to do it without changing x? when I've tried that I get 4.6499999999999995

Comment: @user2613347  yes you can.check my answer.

Comment: @user2613347 that's because the number cannot be represented exactly in the internal number format.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        double x = 0.05;

        double y = (4.6 + x) + 34.2;

        System.out.println("y is " + y);

    }
```

**output:**

```
 y is 38.85
```

Without changing `x`  value

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    double x = 5;

    double y = (4.6 + x/100) + 34.2;

    System.out.println("y is " + y);

}
```

**output:**

```
y is 38.85
```

Comment: @user2613347 Now you have all possible ways.Choose wisely for best suite for your requirement :)